# Add underscore between CamelCase String except continuing uppsercase letter in LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I need to implement a method in C# LINQ that would add an underscore whenever there is a upper case letter appears in a camelcase string. I found this could be easily written in LINQ as

```
string.Concat(value.Select((x, i) => i > 0 && char.IsUpper(x) ? "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString()));
```

For example:

```
ThisIsMyOrderDescription --> This_Is_My_Order_Description
```

However, **if a string contains continuing uppercase letter, we need to avoid adding underscore between each but only after the very last uppercase character**. For example:

```
// using above method would become which is not expected
ThisIsMyAMAZONDescription --> This_Is_My_A_M_A_Z_O_N_Description
// this is what to expect
ThisIsMyAMAZONDescription --> This_Is_My_AMAZON_Description
```

Is it possible or How could we using C# LINQ to perform above scenario? (Note, Regex is not in consideration at this time.)

Comment: Why the requirement to use Linq? Is this an assignment?

Comment: A for loop and a stringbuilder makes more sense in this case IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check the immediate char siblings and add the underscore accordingly:

```
string test = "ThisIsMyAMAZONDescriptionX";
var list = test.Select((x, i) => 
                       (i > 0 
                        && i < test.Length - 1 
                        && char.IsUpper(x) 
                        && (!char.IsUpper(test[i - 1]) 
                            || !char.IsUpper(test[i + 1])) 
                        || (i == test.Length -1 
                            && char.IsUpper(x) 
                            && !char.IsUpper(test[i - 1]))) ? 
                       "_" + x.ToString() : x.ToString());    
var result = string.Concat(list);

Console.WriteLine(result);
//This_Is_My_AMAZON_Description_X
```

HTH

Comment: creating the tuples isn't necessary (note that you never even use `Item2`).  You already have the index and you can just check the previous and next characters of the string with `test[i-1]` and `test[i+1]`.  You just have to include a length check for the second one in case the last letter is a capital (which your code here also needs to handle).

Comment: Please use `test[i-1]` instead of `ElementAt` as it's less wordy and doesn't have to iterate over the characters.

Comment: Great solution. Definitely hard to look at, though.